# Newcomers' Presentation

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, presentations, events

My company has decided to organize a staff meeting event next week to break the ice between employees and I'm glad that they did. There are six newcomers joined the team within four months including me and our managers stated that we will be given 60 seconds to present ourselves.

As you guess, the topics are:

- Life story
- Previous work experience
- Current team & role
- Fun facts about the individual

It appears to be pretty simple but I have problems with being outspoken a bit. I'm afraid of saying things which might be weird and inappropriate.

What is the proper/appropriate way to overcome this presentation? How would you do it in 60 seconds?

Comment: What is the cultural background of the company?

Comment: Keep it absolutely factual.  For point four DON'T try to be funny or clever in any way at all.  State something totally innocuous.  (Example, "I have two dogs" or "I've lived in four countries" or "I recently moved house" or "I enjoy jogging/skiing/tennis/some sport."  Something TOTALLY innocuous.)

Comment: Keep in mind, 60 seconds goes by really fast when you are speaking. If you are using the 4 bullet points you listed, that really isn't enough time for more than 1 or 2 short sentences on each one. I'd bet if you practiced it you would have a hard time keeping it under 60 seconds. That time will be over before you know it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have been given 60 seconds to tell them what you want people to know about you.

- Break it down into a few bullet points on an index card.
- Practice what you are going to say ahead of time
- Do not go into depth on your points.  Make the point and move on.
- You do not have to take the full 60 seconds if you don't need.
- This is just an icebreaker.  No one expects a lengthy speech.  Just stick to your bullets and be done.

Comment: In fact, you haven't been given time for a lengthy speech. 60 seconds goes by really fast. The challenge will be keeping it under that time.

Comment: I'm thinking that one stentence for each point is about right.  Your life story can be as simple as "I grew up in X, and moved to here for reason Y".  You previous work experience is just listing a job title and previous company (no need to list them all).  Current team and role, is rather hard to expand upon, and fun facts?  Just tell them a hobby or outside interest you like (video games, reading, gardening, whatever) odds are nobody is going to even ask you about your hobbies again.